# My loop is not adding anything to my list

Tags: list, loops, texas-instruments

Within my program for my TI 83 Plus, I have a loop that is supposed to add random integers to my list, yet it is not working, here is my code:

```
0->I
While I<10
I+1->I
augment(⌞X,{RandInt(0,52))})
End
Disp (⌞X)
Pause
```

The program ends up just printing {0} Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Because "While" is incorrectly spelled?

Comment: Woops, fixed that, but no thats not the problem, ti 83s don't work that way.